# Is there any other option (resource) for storing data except file or DB?

Tags: informix, oracle-cdc

I am new with CDC (Change Data Capture).
We have to process 16 million transaction per minute. We are using IBM Informix for DB.

My task is to add a feature of storing current transaction id to some resources either File, DB etc. and an API will use this transaction id as a previous transaction id and start from the next transaction id.
But storing to File or DB will not be an option as these are very heavy operations writing in a file or DB.

Is there any other way to resource to store previous transaction id to improve API efficiency.

We are using Java.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  That's a fairly busy system you've got there.  What do you mean by 'transaction ID'?  Is it something that you're going to be managing, or something that's already part of the system, or an ID that Informix creates anyway (and if created by Informix, which ID are you using)?  It isn't clear what you mean by "storing current transaction ID to some resources …".  Please can you edit your question to explain more clearly what you're after.  Are you planning to embed the functionality in the server as an extension, or will it run on clients, or what?

Comment: Is a BIGSERIAL column or a SEQUENCE what you're looking for?  (A SERIAL column won't manage 16 million records per minute for very long since it is a 32-bit signed quantity but always positive, so you'd have enough range for only a couple hours running at full tilt.)   Both BIGSERIAL and SEQUENCE numbers are automatically assigned or generated 64-bit values that are unique to a table or sequence. They could probably be used for your transaction ID if (as I begin to think you mean while re-rereading your question while editing it) you are trying to create an application-managed transaction ID.